# Hibernate does not create table?

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven

I am working on a spring + hibernate based project. Actually, A project is given to me with **Simple Spring Web Maven** Structure (Spring Tool Suit as IDE).

I have successfully imported the project into my STS IDE and have also changed some of hibernate configuration properties so that application will be able to talk to my local PostGreSQL server.

The changes that I have made are as given below:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/schema
jdbc.username=username
jdbc.password=password
```

The **hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto** property is already set to update so I didn't change that.

Then I simply deploy my project to **Pivotal** Server and hibernate get executed and creates around 36 tables inside my DB **schema**. Looks fine !

**My Problem:** In my **hibernate.cfg.XML** file total 100 Java model classes are mapped and they also have @Entity annotation. Then, why **hibernate** is not creating all the remaining tables?

Due to some cause I can't post the code of any of the model class here, I have searched a lot about the problem and applied many different solutions but didn't worked. **Could someone please let me know that what could be the reasons that hibernate can react like this?**

One of my model class which is not created in my DB.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fare_master")
public class FareMaster {
@Id
@Column(name = "fare_id")
@GeneratedValue
private int fareId;

@Column(name = "base_fare_amount")
private double baseFareAmount;

public int getFareId() {
    return fareId;
}

public void setFareId(int fareId) {
    this.fareId = fareId;
}

public double getBaseFareAmount() {
    return baseFareAmount;
}

public void setBaseFareAmount(double baseFareAmount) {
    this.baseFareAmount = baseFareAmount;
}

}
```

And mapping of the class is as follows

```
<mapping class="com.mypackage.model.FareMaster" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Change **hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto** property  to **create-drop** if you want to create tables, setting it to update will just allow you to update existing tables in your DB.

And check your log file to catch errors.

Comment: I already tried create-drop, create but it's not working, still same number of tables are there in my DB

Comment: I used create-drop so my tables are dropped automatically when I deployed my application.

Comment: and it don't create all your tables ?

Comment: No it didn't. what could be cause ?

Comment: you should check if you aren't missing something in your mapping.. or if there is an dropdownlist that you should display to see other tables :p ..

Comment: Everything looks fine till now and actually no need to scroll down as my application already throwing exception that "fare_master" does not exist :)

Comment: can you post your log when tables are creating.. and messages errors

Comment: Thanks @FuSsA for giving me a proper way to find out the exact reason behind the problem. I used log file and when I see in my log file then I encountered the real cause. It's happing because I switched my DB from MySql to PostGreSql and some of the columnDef are not compatible with PostGreSql so HIbernate was not creating that tables.

Comment: Logger was the key idea that you have given to me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

After a very long time efforts, I came to a conclusion that for this problem or similar type of other problems we should always follow the basic rules

1.) First, Be sure about your problem that means the Exact Issue causing this type of error.

2.) And to find out the exact issue use **Logger** in your application and you will definitely save lot of time.

In my case this is happening becasue I have switched my DB from **MySql** to **PostGreSql** and some of syntax in **columnDefinition**( a parameterin in @Column Annotation) was not compatible with my new DB. As I used again **MySql** everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a schema.sql file under your projects, hibernate does not create tables.

Please remove it and try again.